# Printer found in dmesg but not in cups

Tags: debian, usb, cups, printer

I am running Debian Linux Stable (regularly updated) with LXDE desktop and it is otherwise running very well. I have HP Laserjet 1020 connected to it via USB. When I switch on the printer, I get following entries in 'desg' command output:

```
[ 5704.468021] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 5704.636216] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=2b17
[ 5704.636221] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5704.636223] usb 1-7: Product: HP LaserJet 1020
[ 5704.636226] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
[ 5704.636228] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: JL1CQE6
[ 5704.639828] usblp 1-7:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 7 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x2B17
[ 5708.797352] usblp0: removed
```

(I think there may be a problem in last line)

In /dev folder, there is not entry with 'usb' in name:

```
root@debian-netinst:/dev# ls -ltrh | grep -i usb
root@debian-netinst:/dev#
```

There are some entries having 'lp':

```
root@debian-netinst:/dev# ls -ltrh | grep -i lp
crw-rw-r--  1 root lp       99,   0 Aug 24 10:42 parport0
crw-rw----  1 root lp        6,   0 Aug 24 10:42 lp0
root@debian-netinst:/dev#
```

The printer is not shown in browser at site: `http://localhost:631/`

The printer is also not found when I run `hp-setup -i` as root and select usb option to search for printers.

Where is the problem and how can this be solved?

Edit: The command `lsusb` also finds the printer:

```
# lsusb
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 03f0:2b17 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1020
```

Edit:
I could not solve the problem despite multiple attempts. Since this was an upgrade from Debian 8 (to 9) where I had installed and removed many programs (and some desktops also), I formatted the partition and did a fresh install of Debian-9. The printer works OK on this new installation.

Comment: You should show lsusb result if this command implemented in your distribution

Comment: lsusb finds the printer

Comment: You need to add a CUPS entry for the printer. This can be done via command line or via the web interface.

Comment: Can you tell briefly how to do it or give a web link for that?

Comment: Printer is not found in http://localhost:631/

Comment: Have you got the *hplip* and *hpijs-ppds* packages installed?

Comment: Yes, I have. Please see edit in my question above on how it got solved.

Comment: Thanks for reporting how you solved it but please don't edit questions to show your solution. Instead, post an answer and accept it. That way, the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: Formatting and reinstallation of system is not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the page http://localhost:631/admin/ you should have a button "add printer". after clicked on it, the browser will ask you your login and password of your end user (don't use root login). You will see a list . Your usb printer should be there

Comment: My printer does not appear in that list! That is what this question is all about.

Comment: So choice `Local Printers: HP Printer (HPLIP) ` and click on continue then write `usb://HP/LaserJet%1020` in the connection case of the browser page  (source : http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/cups/hp1020.html)

Comment: No HPLIP local printer choice is there. Only choices under Local printers are "Serial Port #1" and "LPT #1". Also, I have to be root else there is "permission denied" error.

Comment: your CUPs is not configured well, the end user should able to add printer.

Comment: Should I reinstall it?

Comment: As you upgraded your version of your system you should